# How to show incomplete items in the first time then complete them next in beamer?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

In beamer, I would like to show two incomplete items at the start of the slide. Next, I would like to complete the items. What I want is like: I present two items to the audience (so I show the items to the audience) and I ask them to guess what are these items? and next I will give them the right answer item by item.

So I will have something like:

In the first time, I have:

- Item 1:
- Item 2:

Then, I have:

- Item 1: text1
- Item 2:

Then, I have:

- Item 1: text1
- Item 2: text2

I did this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item<1,2-3> Item1: text1
   \item<1,3-3> Item2: text2 
\end{enumerate}
```

But the result is not what I want.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach with explicit `\onslide` settings.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item<1-3> Item1: \onslide<2-3>{text1}
   \item<1-3> Item2: \onslide<3-3>{text2}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are various overlay specifications (see `beamer` documentation for details). I use several of them here. One major difference is that the content of `\only{}` does not occupy space while not shown, but the others do. Using `\only{}` can cause material to move around on a frame, but can be useful when replacing one thing with another. Another difference is the content of `\onslide{}` and `\uncover{}` can be hidden to varying degrees, depending on the setting of `\setbeamercovered{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Item1: \only<2->{text1}
   \item Item2: \onslide<3->{text2}
   \item Item4: \uncover<4->{text3}
   \item Item3: \visible<5->{text4}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]